# How to know auto renewable Product renews in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, auto-renewing

I am using using in App purchase in my app. In sandbox mode validity of product reduced http://dev-ios.blogspot.in/2011/05/validity-time-auto-renewables-in.html
So how can I check whether the product is renewed or not?
and renewed according to correct renewable time?

Comment: Please follow this tutorial http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/29/at-newsstand-and-subscriptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever your app is open you want to post the `receipt-data` and `password` to the apple server.

It returns with a `STATUS` :

- if status is `0` subscription is auto renewed.
- if status is `21000` The App Store could not read the JSON object you provided.
- if status is `21002` The data in the receipt-data property was malformed.
- if Status is `21003` The receipt could not be authenticated.
- if status is `21004` The shared secret you provided does not match the shared secret on file for your account.
- if Status is `21005` The receipt server is not currently available.
- if status is `21006` This receipt is valid but the subscription has expired. When this status code is returned to your server, the receipt data is also decoded and returned as part of the response.
- if status is `21007` This receipt is a sandbox receipt, but it was sent to the production service for verification.
- if status is `21008` This receipt is a production receipt, but it was sent to the sandbox service for verification.

[Refer this  link for auto renewable subscriptions.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW5)

Comment: Thanks it means once the autorenewable product is purchased at device end then all checks like product is still up for that user is done at server end(verification of recipt with shared secret key).one more thing if it is renewing properly at server side they will recieve status again 0 if everything is fine with product and the same transaction id? or the transaction id will change after renewal?

Comment: you can simply store the original receipt and just send that to Apple each time for verification. For ARS Apple will always respond with the latest receipt for that product ID. So you don't necessarily have to store the new receipts